# What is OR in JOIN eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

what is OR clause in eloquent where join with 2 case

in basic SQL this query is work but that should i translate to laravel eloquent

```
SELECT u.name as user_name, b.id_booking, s.start_time, s.end_time, b.user_email, b.payment_status, b.payment_type FROM bookings b JOIN users u ON u.email = b.user_email OR u.email = b.client_emailJOIN schedules s ON b.id_schedule = s.id_schedule;
```

but in laravel

```
public function showByClient()
{
    try {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $listBooking = Booking::select('users.name as user_name', 'bookings.id_booking', 'schedules.start_time', 'schedules.end_time', 'bookings.client_email', 'bookings.payment_status', 'bookings.payment_type')
                                ->join('users','users.email','=','bookings.user_email')->or('users','users.email','=',$user->email)
                                ->join('schedules','schedules.id_schedule','=','bookings.id_schedule')
                                // ->where('bookings.client_email',$user->email)
                                ->get();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Failed retrieved data.' . $e->getMessage(),
            'serve' => []
        ], 500);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Succesfully retrieved data.',
        'serve' => $listBooking
    ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function showByClient()
{
    try {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $listBooking = Booking::join('users', function($join){
                                $join->on('users.email','=','bookings.user_email'); 
                                $join->orOn('users.email','=','bookings.client_email');
                        })
                        ->join('schedules','schedules.id_schedule','=','bookings.id_schedule')
                        ->select('users.name as user_name', 'bookings.id_booking', 'schedules.start_time', 'schedules.end_time', 'bookings.client_email', 'bookings.payment_status', 'bookings.payment_type')
                        ->get();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Failed retrieved data.' . $e->getMessage(),
            'serve' => []
        ], 500);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Succesfully retrieved data.',
        'serve' => $listBooking
    ], 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public function showByClient()
{
    try {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $listBooking = Booking::select('users.name as user_name', 'bookings.id_booking', 'schedules.start_time', 'schedules.end_time', 'bookings.client_email', 'bookings.payment_status', 'bookings.payment_type')
                        ->join('users', function($join){
                                $join->on('users.email','=','bookings.user_email'); 
                                $join->orOn('users.id','=','bookings.client_email');
                        })
                        ->join('schedules','schedules.id_schedule','=','bookings.id_schedule')
                        ->get();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Failed retrieved data.' . $e->getMessage(),
            'serve' => []
        ], 500);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Succesfully retrieved data.',
        'serve' => $listBooking
    ], 200);
}
```